# How to log in separate lines while using set in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, set

I'm logging All the updated Fields updated in an api call through set but they are logging in same line

And I need to print them in different lines, like this

REQUIRED

```
Email updated 
FirstName Updated
```

**Service class:** logging like this

```
 final var userModifiedFields =userUpdater.getUpdatedFields();

            if ((!userModifiedFields.isEmpty())) {
                log.info("Updated Fields : " + String.join("  ", userModifiedFields));
            }

 public Set<String> getUpdatedFields() {
            return updatedFields;
        }
```

**Current Output**

```
 Updated Fields : Email  FirstName
```

Required output mentied above

Comment: You want to break a log message into multiple  lines? Really?

Comment: Are `Email updated` & `FirstName Updated` the value of the `String` objects in your set?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `String.join` to concatenate all the fields into a single line, we're using a loop to log each field separately.

```
if (!userModifiedFields.isEmpty()) {
    log.info("Updated Fields:");
    for (String field : userModifiedFields) {
        log.info(field);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

Use `Set#forEach`.

```
userUpdater.getUpdatedFields().forEach ( log :: info )
```

### Details

The [Answer by Mohanty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77005304/642706) is correct.

We can make an alternative version of that code by making an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html) of the [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) via [`Set#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)), and passing a [method reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_syntax#Method_references).

Example data:

```java
Set < String > set = Set.of ( "Email updated" , "FirstName Updated" );
```

Example code:

```java
set.forEach ( System.out :: println );
```

Result:

```
FirstName Updated
Email updated
```

For your specific case, replace that example method reference with `log :: info`.

```
set.forEach ( log :: info ) ;
```

Notice how there is no need to check for `isEmpty`.

You can even drop your `var userModifiedFields`.

```
userUpdater.getUpdatedFields().forEach ( log :: info ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must **use** for each-loop for **field** underneath the **set** and get each **field** from the **set**.

Here is the code shown below

```
final Set<String> userModifiedFields = userUpdater.getUpdatedFields();

if (!userModifiedFields.isEmpty()) {
    log.info("Updated Fields:");
    for (String field : userModifiedFields) {
        log.info(field + " updated");
    }

}
```